# Relational Notations for "must be" and "occasionally"

Tags: relations

I have seen in some places; single relational symbols (particularly $\neq , \lt, \gt, \leqslant, \geqslant $) are being used for more than one  sense; usually 2 sense, such as (1.) "exactly" or "always" and (2.) "Not necessarily", or "There may be exceptions". My question is; is there a more specific notation for these 2 usage (1.) "exactly" or "always" and (2.) "Not necessarily"? Maybe a set-theory notation?

Such as

$$ \begin{array}{lr} a-b \neq b-a ~~~&~~~ ...1 \end{array}$$

and also

$$ \begin{array}{lr} a \neq a+1 ~~~&~~~ ...2 \end{array}$$

But there are difference between the sense of these two $\neq$ s.

**The relationship- 1**. is an attempt to demonstrate **subtraction is not commutative.** But the $\neq$ sign is **not** used in the sense that $a-b$ will be always unequal with $b-a$. Such as if $a=0$ and $b=0$ then $(a-b) = 0-0 = (b-a) = 0-0$. For any given values of $a-b$ we can not "conclude" $a-b$ would be always unequal to $b-a$.

But the **relationship 2.** tells the terms $a$ and $a+1$ will be always unequal. And in return, for any given values for $a$ we can conclude $a+1$ is always unequal from $a$.

Now is there any notation to distinguish **"Always Unequal"** and **"Occasionally unequal"**? (and for similar situations occur for inequalities? )

NB. In case of **Relationship-1**, I could denote the exception in third brackets (  $[ ]$  ) at right hand side of the expression; but in cases all the possible exception could not be figured out; could there be any "General" notation that there are "some" exceptions?

Comment: You can qualify each statement as such:  $\forall a~:~ a\neq a+1$.  Meanwhile $\exists (a,b)~:~ a-b\neq b-a$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanx Plz. Make it an answer.

Comment: Could anyone plz edit my question to put **...1** and **...2** at right hand side (with a few space distance) of respective relations? (Preferably using MathJax commands).

Comment: `\begin{array}{lr} a\neq a+1~~~&~~~...2\end{array}` yields $$\begin{array}{lr} a\neq a+1~~~&~~~...2\end{array}$$.  See more at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Honestly, I would just use words.  You can say "It is not always true that $a-b = b-a$."  Usually in math writing we eschew using logical symbols like $\neg, \forall, \exists$ unless there is a special reason.

Comment: @JairTaylor Still, it is an answer.  ¬,∀,∃  is an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantifiers are needed. No truth-value can be assigned to "$a-b=b-a$" as it stands.

The sentence  $\forall a \forall b\;(a-b=b-a)$ is false.

The sentence $\exists a \exists b\;(a-b=b-a)$ is true.

A sentence such as "$a-b=b-a$ is true for some, but not all, $a,b$" is often expressed as "In general, $a-b\ne b-a.$"

Comment: Thanks, [Quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) would be the concept I was looking for.